# Merge Sort implementation not working as expected

Tags: c++, sorting, c++14, mergesort

I've been trying to implement the merge sort; but the implementation somehow is incorrect — the output contains values that were not part of the original array. I've tried comparing it to the implementation (working) of other people but can't seem to find the mistake.

The code is:-

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
void Merge (int A[], int lo, int hi, int mid){
    int i = lo;
    int k = 0;
    int j = mid+1;
    int R[hi-lo];

    while(i<=mid && j<=hi){
        if(A[i]<A[j]){
            R[k]=A[i];
            cout << A[i] << "; " << A[j] << "      " << i << "        " << j << endl;
            i++;
        }else {
            R[k]=A[j];
            cout << A[i] << "; " << A[j] << "      " << i << "        " << j << endl;
            j++;
        }k++;
    }
    while(i<=lo){
        R[k]=R[i];
        i++;k++;
    }
    while(j<=hi){
        R[k]=R[j];
        j++;k++;
    }
    int count =0;
    for(i=lo; i<hi; i++){
        A[i]=R[count];
        count++;
        cout << count << "    ;    " << i << "-/-/-/-/-/-/-" << flush;
    }
}
void mergeSort(int A[], int lo, int hi){
    //if(hi-lo+1<2)return;
    if (lo<hi){
    int mid = (lo+hi)/2;
    mergeSort(A, lo, mid);
    mergeSort(A, mid+1, hi);
    Merge (A, lo, hi, mid);}
}

int main(){
    int A[] = {1,5,3,4,8,9,150,7,51,65};
    int hi = sizeof(A)/sizeof(int);
    cout << hi << endl;
    mergeSort(A,0, hi);
    cout << endl << endl << endl << endl;
    for(int i=0; i<=hi; i++){
        cout<<A[i]<< "; " << flush;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I tried to search for similar Q(S), but couldn't find one.

Comment: *I've tried comparing it to the implentation(working) of other people* -- You should be debugging your version instead of trying to find line-by-line what differences you have.  Second, `int R[hi-lo];` is not valid C++, as arrays in C++ can only be declared using a constant expression to denote the number of entries..

Comment: Just a guess, but the `R` array (ignoring the illegality of its declaration) looks like it might be too small; if `hi` is a valid index into the source array, the size of `R` should probably be `hi - lo + 1`. As currently written it holds one less element than the source array.

Comment: @PeteBecker  First of all thanks for replying. Now, even after making the declaration of R legal(didn'tKnowAboutTheConstFactor) and correcting the length of it(hi-lo+1) The output still remains the same.

Comment: AND @PaulMcKenzie

Comment: @vibster its time to use your debugger to step line by line through your code (looking at the variables at each step) to see where it does something you did not expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your implementation is a mix of boundary inclusions and wrong arrays.

First, look at the 2 last while loops in merge, you did:  `R[k]=R[i];`when you meant  `R[k]=A[i];`

On the same function, your for loop is missing an iteration, the loop guard should be `i<=hi` instead of `i<hi`.

The initialisation of hi is also wrong, as you initialised it to the number of elements rather than the last index, you should have subtracted -1.

Also I have no idea what your print code was doing so I commented out and added my own, that I found more clear.

I corrected your code as follows:

```
   #include <iostream>

using namespace std;
void Merge (int A[], int lo, int hi, int mid){
    int i = lo;
    int k = 0;
    int j = mid+1;
    int R[hi-lo];

    cout << "input" << endl;
    for(int i=lo; i<=mid; i++)
        cout << A[i] << " ";
    cout << endl;
    for(int i=mid+1; i<=hi; i++)
        cout << A[i] << " ";

    cout << endl;

    while(i<=mid && j<=hi){
        if(A[i]<A[j]){
            R[k]=A[i];
            //cout << A[i] << "; " << A[j] << "      " << i << "        " << j << endl;
            i++;
        }else {
            R[k]=A[j];
            //cout << A[i] << "; " << A[j] << "      " << i << "        " << j << endl;
            j++;
        }k++;
    }
    while(i<=mid){
        R[k]=A[i];
        i++;k++;
    }
    while(j<=hi){
        R[k]=A[j];
        j++;k++;
    }
    int count =0;
    for(i=lo; i<=hi; i++){
        A[i]=R[count];
        count++;
        //cout << count << "    ;    " << i << "-/-/-/-/-/-/-" << flush;
    }

    cout << "output:" << endl;
    for(int i=lo; i<=hi; i++)
        cout << A[i] << " ";
    cout << endl;
}
void mergeSort(int A[], int lo, int hi){
    //if(hi-lo+1<2)return;
    if (lo<hi){
    int mid = (lo+hi)/2;
    mergeSort(A, lo, mid);
    mergeSort(A, mid+1, hi);
    Merge (A, lo, hi, mid);}
}

int main(){
    int A[] = {1,5,3,4,8,9,150,7,51,65};
    int hi = sizeof(A)/sizeof(int) -1;
    cout << hi << endl;
    mergeSort(A,0, hi);
    cout << endl << endl << endl << endl;
    for(int i=0; i<=hi; i++){
        cout<<A[i]<< "; " << flush;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Also, you fixed `while (i <= lo)` to `while (i <= mid)` in the 'merge the rest' loop.

Comment: @Makogan Thanks! As for all that output code I was trying to track the various variables as for some reason my debugger wasn't working. Thanks again!